# unzip with options to directory and update only

Tags: unzip

How to write an unzip command to unzip a zip file with this "options"

```
 --  files go to specific dir .. should be like this -d ~/home/myDir   
 --  only unzip files which are newer or not already there .. should be -u
```

Problem any notation I tried failed. Any suggestion?

Comment: Which tool do you use? Each tool has it's own options..

Comment: I'm on Raspberry/Wheezy  and doing the debian unzip

Answer (score 0):

Upps ... tried with another writing and found

```
unzip -u {zipfile} -d {destinationDir}
```

is what I'm looking for

;)